# Increase and decrease SVG shape - JS

Tags: javascript, html, function, svg

I would like you to help me for a thing here, for a function to increase and then decrease `SVG` shape when it hits limit.

It should go from 3 to 6 and then 6 to 3 and so on... but instead it goes from 3 to 6 and then 6 to minus infinite. And I don't understand why.

Here is my code :

```
var size = 3;
var sizeManager = 1;

function increaseAnimation(el){

var elem = document.getElementById(el);

  elem.style.transform = "scale("+size+")";
  timer = setTimeout('increaseAnimation(\''+el+'\',3000)');
  size=size+0.005*sizeManager;

  if(size >= 6){
    sizeManager=sizeManager*-1;
  }

  if (size <= 3){
    sizeManager=sizeManager*+1;
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting with the lines `sizeManager=sizeManager*-1;` and `sizeManager=sizeManager*+1;`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I would like it to reverse the increase of the scale to make it decrease,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weird setTimeout implementation, with bound was broken.
There's also the issue that your sizeManager is not properly reflecting:

```
function increaseAnimation(id, interval) {
    var size = 1;
    var velocity = 0.05;
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);


    function iterate() {
        elem.style.transform = "scale(" + size + ")";

        size += velocity;

        if (size > 2 || size < 1) {
            velocity *= -1; // velocity reflected
        }
    }

    var timer = setInterval(iterate, interval);
    return function stop() {
        clearInterval(timer)
    }
}
```

I also added a stop function which you can call at a later point.

```
var stopper = increaseAnimation("content", 16);
setTimeout(stopper, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is with the line `sizeManager=sizeManager*+1;` Multiplying a number by one doesn't change it. You basically want to toggle sizeManager between -1 and +1, and you can do so by multiplying by -1, regardless of whether it is currently negative or positive.

I've tested this code and it seems to work:

```
var size = 3;
var sizeManager = 1;

function increaseAnimation(el) {

    var elem = document.getElementById(el);

    elem.style.transform = "scale(" + size + ")";
    timer = setTimeout("increaseAnimation('" + el + "', 3000)");
    size += 0.005 * sizeManager;

    if (size >= 6 || size <= 3) {
        sizeManager *= -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Full HTML for a POC demo at: https://pastebin.com/GW0Ncr9A

Holler, if you have questions.

```
function Scaler(elementId, minScale, maxScale, deltaScale, direction, deltaMsecs) {
    var scale = (1 == direction)?minScale:maxScale;
    var timer = null;

    function incrementScale() {
        var s = scale + deltaScale*direction;
        if (s < minScale || s > maxScale) direction *= -1;
        return scale += deltaScale*direction;
    };
    function doScale(s) {
        document.getElementById(elementId).style.transform = 'scale(' + s + ')';
    };

    this.getDeltaMsecs = function() {return deltaMsecs;};
    this.setTimer = function(t) {timer = t;};

    this.run = function() {doScale(incrementScale());};
    this.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        this.setTimer(null);
    };
};

var scaler = new Scaler('avatar', 3, 6, .05, 1, 50);

function toggleScaler(ref) {
    if ('run scaler' == ref.value) {
        ref.value = 'stop scaler';
        scaler.setTimer(setInterval('scaler.run()', scaler.getDeltaMsecs()));
    }
    else {
        scaler.stop();
        ref.value = 'run scaler';
    }
};
```